# What’s a good scale robust similarity metric?

Tags: optimization, experiment-design, random-allocation, cosine-similarity

Context: While designing an experiment, there is interest from leadership in pairing control and test units together such that every (test, control) pair are as categorically similar as possible.

Typically in an experiment, we would have a test group and control group, and compare the difference of their means.

However, in this experiment, the goal is to infer a distribution over Delta(X, Y) where every (x[i], y[i]) are sufficiently similar for analysis.

Sidebar—I’m not familiar with this form of design; does it have a name?

I’m quite comfortable with mixed integer linear programming. My goal would be to divide my N units into groups of 2, such that the vector similarity of each pair is maximally similar.

However, some of the vector features are bounded [0,1] while others are continuous.

I see two ways forward, either (1) use a scale resistant similarity metric—I think that cosine similarity might work. Or (2) pre-process vectors such that each is standardized, normalized, or something else then use Euclidean distance.

What is the preferred approach?

Comment: Although it's hard to say, given that the meaning of "Delta(X,Y)" is unclear, but it sounds like you intend to conduct a [case-control study](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms/def/case-control-study).

Comment: Say that in a study, I want to see how athletes respond to a sports drink where the parameter of interest is theta, probability of winning their sports event. Further, suppose that my athletes have various ages, heights, weights, and of course, sports. Each athlete has a vector [age, height, weight, sport]. Now, I can compare athletes in terms of their vector similarity. `Cosine_similarity(x,y) =1` would imply that two athletes, x & y, are identical in terms of age, weight, height, and sport.

Comment: So the goal is to divide the N athletes into groups of two, such that the summed vector similarity across all pairs is maximized. (Eg maximize cosine_similarity, minimize  euclidean distance, etc). So my question is-- which similarity metric is best to optimize with this context in mind?

Comment: Normally, I would randomly allocate athletes to test and control groups, infer the win sports win rate for each group, then get the posterior distribution over $theta_x - theta_y$.

Comment: However, in this context, there is one $theta_{x_i} - theta_{y_i}$ for every $pair_i$ in the study.